# Grails, Joda-Time plugin, TimePicker nullable not working

Tags: grails, jodatime, gsp

I have a domain class with the attributes start + end, both of them are LocalTime (Joda-Time plugin). I want the end Time to be nullable. For this purpose I used the following constraint: `end nullable: true`. Scaffolding is realized through the Joda template and it's working pretty good. The only problem is that selecting nothing with the timepicker for the end property results in: `Cant populate a class org.joda.time.LocalTime without a hour`.

This is the generated code in the view:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: dailyBookingInstance, field: 'end', 'error')} ">
    <label for="end">
        <g:message code="dailyBooking.end.label" default="End" />
    </label>
    <joda:timePicker name="end" value="${dailyBookingInstance?.end}" default="none" noSelection="['': '']"></joda:timePicker>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a binding error (http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Joda-Time-Plugin-Fields-nullable-td4655494.html)

Comment: Yes I saw this too, but dont really know what to do with it since it doesnt provide a solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a binding error - [Joda Time Plugin - Fields nullable?](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Joda-Time-Plugin-Fields-nullable-td4655494.html)

One work around is--

Change field name in the view, say `time`

```
<joda:timePicker name="time" value="${myDomainInstance?.end}" default="none" noSelection="['': '']"/>
```

and only populate this in your domain instance if data exists, like this

```
def save(MyDomain myDomainInstance) {

  if(params.time_minute && params.time_hour){
    myDomainInstance.end = new LocalTime(params.int('time_hour'), params.int('time_minute'))
    myDomainInstance.validate()
  }

  //Other save code
}
```

Hope this helps..,.

Comment: Thanks, but now It says "No such property (time) for class" since its not defined in my domain class.

Comment: OK, got it, just a small change I forgot. in `joda:timePicker` tag value should be `"${myDomainInstance?.end}"`. I have updated my answer. Try once again.

Comment: This lead to another problem. Now I cant update the "end" field anymore, it doesnt change the value. Do you know what I have to edit in my controller or gsps to make it work?

Comment: You need to copy paste if statement from save action (as in the answer).

Comment: Yes I figured that out, it works for the most functions. But if I want to update it to "Null" (nothing selected) it just keeps the old value. Is it possible to set update the "end" to null?

Comment: Then add an else block and assign `null` in `myDomainInstance.end`.